# Provider Issue: Could not find the correct Provider<List<PostsModel>> above ListPosts$ Widget"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling

I am encountering an issue in my Flutter application related to the Provider package. The error message I am receiving is:

"Another exception was thrown: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List> above this ListPosts$ Widget."

this is my code :

```
class ListPosts extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListPosts({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListPosts> createState() => _ListPostsState();
}

class _ListPostsState extends State<ListPosts> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final posts = Provider.of<List<PostsModel>>(context) ?? [];
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final post = posts[index];
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(post.creator),
          subtitle: Text(post.tweet),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```